# Send Email from R with body as integers or list

Tags: r, email, sendmailr

```
finlist <- 1:10

library(mailR)
sender <- "SENDER@gmail.com"
recipients <- c("Recipent@gmail.com")
send.mail(from = sender,
to = recipients,
subject="From R",
body = finlist,
smtp = list(host.name = "smtp.gmail.com", port = 465,
user.name="SENDER@gmail.com", passwd="Password", ssl=TRUE),
authenticate = TRUE,
send = TRUE)
```

The above should send out an Email with subject body as 1, 2, 3, ...10.
However the following error is received.

> Error in file.exists(body) : invalid 'file' argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try 
`body =paste(finlist, collapse = ",")`

Comment: Thanks, is there anyway to have the numbers, one below the other as in. (presently its horizontal, would like to have it vertical)

Comment: I cant fully understand you but may be you need to try add `"\n"` somwhere/ for examples:  `body =paste(finlist, collapse = "\n")` -- give you all numer as column  or `body=paste0(paste(finlist[1:9], collapse = ","),'\n',finlist[10])` -- only last numeric on new row